# Rewrite by lua : Match host

Tags: nginx, lua

I have this [lua](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/) script that redirect the user based on his browser laungage.

```
location = / {
    rewrite_by_lua '
        for lang in (ngx.var.http_accept_language .. ","):gmatch("([^,]*),") do
            if string.sub(lang, 0, 2) == "en" then
                ngx.redirect("/en/index.html")
            end
            if string.sub(lang, 0, 2) == "nl" then
                ngx.redirect("/nl/index.html")
            end
            if string.sub(lang, 0, 2) == "de" then
                ngx.redirect("/de/index.html")
            end
        end
        ngx.redirect("/en/index.html")
    ';
}
```

I only want to match url that ends with `mysite.org`
Any idea how I can add the criteria?

the result sould be something like this:

```
if string.sub(lang, 0, 2) == "nl" and host == "mysite.org" then
                    ngx.redirect("/nl")
                end
```

Comment: Irrelevant to your main question but, in normal Lua, indices are one-based so you probably meant `string.sub(lang,1,2)` which can also written as `lang:sub(1,2)`.  But I don't know if nginx has a modified Lua with zero-based indices.

Answer (score 0):

Without having full details of your exact input, I think the below should work:

```
location = / {
    rewrite_by_lua '
        for lang in (ngx.var.http_accept_language .. ","):gmatch("([^,]*),") do
          lang = lang:sub(1, 2)
          if host:match("mysite%.org$") then
            if lang == "en" then ngx.redirect("/en/index.html")
            elseif lang == "nl" then ngx.redirect("/nl/index.html")
            elseif lang == "de" then ngx.redirect("/de/index.html")
            end
          end
        end
        ngx.redirect("/en/index.html")
    ';
}
```

Also note the use of `elseif` to make code shorter.  On another note, explicit checking for 'en' language could be omitted as it is the default fall-through case.